# How to unquote a urlencoded unicode string in python?

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding, urllib, w3c

I have a unicode string like "Tanım" which is encoded as "Tan%u0131m" somehow. How can i convert this encoded string back to original unicode. 
Apparently urllib.unquote does not support unicode.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

%uXXXX is a [non-standard encoding scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Non-standard_implementations) that has been rejected by the w3c, despite the fact that an implementation continues to live on in JavaScript land.

The more common technique seems to be to UTF-8 encode the string and then % escape the resulting bytes using %XX. This scheme is supported by urllib.unquote:

```
>>> urllib2.unquote("%0a")
'\n'
```

Unfortunately, if you really **need** to support %uXXXX, you will probably have to roll your own decoder. Otherwise, it is likely to be far more preferable to simply UTF-8 encode your unicode and then % escape the resulting bytes.

A more complete example:

```
>>> u"Tanım"
u'Tan\u0131m'
>>> url = urllib.quote(u"Tanım".encode('utf8'))
>>> urllib.unquote(url).decode('utf8')
u'Tan\u0131m'
```

Comment: 'urllib2.unquote' should be 'urllib.unquote'

Comment: Interesting that a URI is a percent-encoded byte-string, rather than a character-string.

Comment: @jamtoday not necessarly, in Python 2.7.5+ you can use `urllib2.unquote` just try `print(dir(urllib2))`

Comment: urllib.unquote(url.encode('utf-8')) worked for me instead

Comment: is it bad practice to do something like `unquote(urlencode())`?

Answer (score 11):

```
def unquote(text):
    def unicode_unquoter(match):
        return unichr(int(match.group(1),16))
    return re.sub(r'%u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})',unicode_unquoter,text)
```

Comment: This only works for Python 2, unfortunately, which is [rapidly approaching its end-of-life](https://pythonclock.org/). It's not hard to correct for to make this Python 2 and 3 compatible (`try: unichr`, `except NameError: unichr = chr`), but this version does not handle surrogate pairs. The intent of the `%hhhh` escape format was to encode *UTF-16* codepoints, so for non-BMP sequences (such as a large number of emoji) you'd get an invalid string on anything but a UCS-2 Python 2 build.

Answer (score 7):

This will do it if you absolutely have to have this (I really do agree with the cries of "non-standard"):

```
from urllib import unquote

def unquote_u(source):
    result = unquote(source)
    if '%u' in result:
        result = result.replace('%u','\\u').decode('unicode_escape')
    return result

print unquote_u('Tan%u0131m')

> Tanım
```

Comment: A slightly pathological case, but: unquote_u('Tan%25u0131m') --> u'Tan\u0131m' rather than 'Tan%u0131' like it should. Just a reminder of why you probably don't want to write a decoder unless you really need it.

Comment: I totally agree. Which is why I really was not keen to offer an actual solution. These things are never so straightforward. The O.P. might have been desperate though, and I think this complements your excellent answer.

Comment: This only works for Python 2, unfortunately, which is [rapidly approaching its end-of-life](https://pythonclock.org/). The use of `unicode_escape` makes it a little harder to correct for Python 3 use (you'd need to encode to utf-8 first), but this version does not handle surrogate pairs. The intent of the `%hhhh` escape format was to encode *UTF-16* codepoints, so for non-BMP sequences (such as a large number of emoji) you'd get an invalid string on anything but a UCS-2 Python 2 build.

Answer (score 4):

there is a bug in the above version where it freaks out sometimes when there are both ascii encoded and unicode encoded characters in the string. I think its specifically when there are characters from the upper 128 range like '\xab' in addition to unicode.

eg. "%5B%AB%u03E1%BB%5D" causes this error.

I found if you just did the unicode ones first, the problem went away:

```
def unquote_u(source):
  result = source
  if '%u' in result:
    result = result.replace('%u','\\u').decode('unicode_escape')
  result = unquote(result)
  return result
```

Comment: \xab is not a character but a byte.  In effect your example "string" contains both bytes and characters, which is not valid as a single string in any language I know of.

Comment: What would `"%5B%AB%u03E1%BB%5D"` decode as? 0x5B 0xAB and 0xBB 0x5D are hardly valid UTF-8 sequences.

Comment: @wberry: I've seen real-life cases (a Java library somewhere) that encodes some ASCII codepoints like spaces to `%hh` sequences, and anything over 0x7F to `%uhhhh` sequences. Terrible, but parsable.

Answer (score 4):

You have a URL using a [non-standard encoding scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Non-standard_implementations), rejected by standards bodies but still being produced by some encoders. The Python `urllib.parse.unquote()` function can't handle these.

Creating your own decoder is not that hard, luckily. `%uhhhh` entries are meant to be *UTF-16* codepoints here, so we need to take [surrogate pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U+010000_to_U+10FFFF) into account. I've also seen `%hh` codepoints mixed in, for added confusion.

With that in mind, here is a decoder which works in both Python 2 and Python 3, provided you pass in a `str` object in Python 3 (Python 2 cares less):

```
try:
    # Python 3
    from urllib.parse import unquote
    unichr = chr
except ImportError:
    # Python 2
    from urllib import unquote

def unquote_unicode(string, _cache={}):
    string = unquote(string)  # handle two-digit %hh components first
    parts = string.split(u'%u')
    if len(parts) == 1:
        return parts
    r = [parts[0]]
    append = r.append
    for part in parts[1:]:
        try:
            digits = part[:4].lower()
            if len(digits) < 4:
                raise ValueError
            ch = _cache.get(digits)
            if ch is None:
                ch = _cache[digits] = unichr(int(digits, 16))
            if (
                not r[-1] and
                u'\uDC00' <= ch <= u'\uDFFF' and
                u'\uD800' <= r[-2] <= u'\uDBFF'
            ):
                # UTF-16 surrogate pair, replace with single non-BMP codepoint
                r[-2] = (r[-2] + ch).encode(
                    'utf-16', 'surrogatepass').decode('utf-16')
            else:
                append(ch)
            append(part[4:])
        except ValueError:
            append(u'%u')
            append(part)
    return u''.join(r)
```

The function is heavily inspired by the [current standard-library implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1f58f4fa6a0e3c60cee8df4a35c8dcf3903acde8/Lib/urllib/parse.py#L569-L627).

Demo:

```
>>> print(unquote_unicode('Tan%u0131m'))
Tanım
>>> print(unquote_unicode('%u05D0%u05D9%u05DA%20%u05DE%u05DE%u05D9%u05E8%u05D9%u05DD%20%u05D0%u05EA%20%u05D4%u05D8%u05E7%u05E1%u05D8%20%u05D4%u05D6%u05D4'))
איך ממירים את הטקסט הזה
>>> print(unquote_unicode('%ud83c%udfd6'))  # surrogate pair

>>> print(unquote_unicode('%ufoobar%u666'))  # incomplete
%ufoobar%u666
```

The function works on Python 2 (tested on 2.4 - 2.7) and Python 3 (tested on 3.3 - 3.8).