# Python Unicode %HH-escaping

Tags: python, unicode

All,

I am working on an application that has a mixture of standard latin-1 characters and other languages. I would like to convert everything to the same "format" so that the Bing translator can understand it. There are two articles that I've looked at.

1. https://dev.laptop.org/ticket/2327 I actually want to do the reverse of this and convert this [http://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/حاسوب](http://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%AD%D8%A7%D8%B3%D9%88%D8%A8) to this http://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%AD%D8%A7%D8%B3%D9%88%D8%A8
2. Similar article but not quite what I was looking for. [How to unquote a urlencoded unicode string in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300445/how-to-unquote-a-urlencoded-unicode-string-in-python)

My method is quite simple...

```
    for w in wiki:
        q = (w[0])
        u = unicode(q, 'utf=8', errors='ignore')
        h = ''
        for c in u:
            h += do something amazing

        doTranslate(h)
```

Can anyone help to shed some light on what I am missing here?

Answer (score 2):

urllib might help. At least this snippet works:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import urllib

w = 'ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/حاسوب'
print urllib.quote (w)
```

Output is

```
ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%AD%D8%A7%D8%B3%D9%88%D8%A8
```

Depending which encoding your input strings have you might need to call encode ('utf-8') prior to passing it to quote()

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now what if my string is part arabic and part latin like this. 'وب (ar)' How do I get around that?

Comment: But my input string is half latin and half arabic.

Comment: Very good point ;-) I am trying to translate some data using the bing translator and it can automatically detect the language. I am just having a hard time figuring out how to translate a string that is in two languages...