# IDNA nameprep Invalid character u'\x94'

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

I have some working url with unicode and trying to apply IDNA encoding

```
test = ur"http://example.com/%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8.22219/"
url_unq = urllib.unquote(test)
print url_unq
print url_unq.encode("idna")
```

The code above fails with:

> File "C:\Python25\lib\encodings\idna.py", line 38, in nameprep
>       raise UnicodeError("Invalid character %r" % c) UnicodeError: Invalid character u'\x94'

What's wrong with my encodings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `\x94` can not be encoded in IDNA - see [RFC3454](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3454):

> 0080-009F; [CONTROL CHARACTERS]

Comment: @Eugene - no? Your second character after `/` is `%94` which is same as `\x94`

Comment: Okay, thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300445/how-to-unquote-a-urlencoded-unicode-string-in-python it's converted now, but now I see that i'm wrong: domain name ASCII encoding but path doesn't - IDNA will not help