# How to decode encodeURIComponent in GAE (python)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, unicode, character-encoding, uri

I have a unicode string that was encoded on the client side using JS encodeURIComponent.

If I use the following in Python locally, I get the expected result:

```
>>> urllib.unquote("Foo%E2%84%A2%20Bar").decode("utf-8")
>>> u'Foo\u2122 Bar'
```

But when I run this in Google App Engine, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/_webapp25.py", line 703, in __call__
    handler.post(*groups)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~kaon-log/2.357769827131038147/main.py", line 143, in post
    path_uni = urllib.unquote(h.path).decode('utf-8')
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_dist/lib/python2.5/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 3-5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I'm still using Python 2.5, in case that makes a difference. What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My guess is that `h.path` is a unicode object. Then `urllib.unquote` would return a unicode object. When `decode` is called on a unicode object at first it is converted to `str` using default encoding (which is ascii) and here you get the `'ascii' codec can't encode` exception.

Here is a proof:

```
>>> urllib.unquote(u"Foo%E2%84%A2%20Bar").decode("utf-8")
...
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 3-5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This should work:

```
urllib.unquote(h.path.encode('utf-8')).decode("utf-8")
```

There is a stackoverflow thread which explains why unicode doesn't work with `urllib.unquote`: [How to unquote a urlencoded unicode string in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300445/how-to-unquote-a-urlencoded-unicode-string-in-python)

Comment: I used urllib.unquote(str(h.path)).decode("utf-8") and it did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Use this class instead of urllib2:

```
class URL(object):
  '''encode/decode requested URL'''
  def __init__(self):
    self.charset = '/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_0123456789.'

  def encode(self,url):
    return ''.join([c if c in self.charset else '%'+c.encode('hex').upper() for c in url])

  def decode(self,url):
    return re.compile('%([0-9a-fA-F]{2})',re.M).sub(lambda m: chr(int(m.group(1),16)), url)
```

Example:

```
  import re
  URL().decode(your URL)
```

Comment: Can you explain why?