# allowing urls as parameters

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I want to save URLs in my database and to do so I implemented the following call:

```
http://myapp.com/save/url_to_be_saved
```

The parameter `url_to_be_saved` can be any URL, as:

```
http://myapp.com/save/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
http://myapp.com/save/http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms
```

How can I make `Django` accept these patterns? My current `myapp.urls` is the following:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^a/signup/$', views.signup, name='signup'),
    url(r'^a/login/$', views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^a/logout/$', views.logout, name='logout'),
    url(r'^a/search/(?P<term>.{1,50})/$', views.search, name='search'),
    url(r'^save/(?P<url>([^a/]){1,50})/$', views.save_url, name='save_url'),
)
```

Comment: Please don't use the title to tag your posts.

Comment: Why? Isn't it how all the other Python-related questions are structured?

Comment: Please read the [help section on tagging](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd allow anything to be passed in the `url`, then I would [validate the url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160737/python-how-to-validate-a-url-in-python-malformed-or-not) in the view:

```
url(r'^save/(?P<url>.*)/$', views.save_url, name='save_url'),
```

Then, the view needs to validate the url:

```
from django.core.validators import URLValidator
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def save_url(request, url):
    url_validator = URLValidator(verify_exists=False)
    try:
        url_validator(url)
    except ValidationError:
        print 'Not a valid URL'
```

You would also probably need to [`unquote`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300445/how-to-unquote-a-urlencoded-unicode-string-in-python) the url before validating it.

Comment: That's great. The combination of the regex and validation does what I want. Thanks.