# How do I encode/decode percent-encoded (URL) strings in Python?

Tags: python, encoding

How do I decode percent-encoded characters to ordinary unicode characters?

```
"Lech_Kaczy%C5%84ski"    ⟶    "Lech_Kaczyński"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unquote a urlencoded unicode string in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300445/how-to-unquote-a-urlencoded-unicode-string-in-python)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For Python 2, using [`urllib.unquote`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote):

```
import urllib
urllib.unquote("Lech_Kaczy%C5%84ski").decode('utf8')
```

This will return a unicode string:

```
u'Lech_Kaczy\u0144ski'
```

which you can then print and process as usual. For example:

```
print(urllib.unquote("Lech_Kaczy%C5%84ski").decode('utf8'))
```

will result in

```
Lech_Kaczyński
```

Comment: It gives me `Lech_Kaczy\xc5\x84ski`, instead of `Lech_Kaczyński`

Comment: That doesn't look like a unicode string, are you sure you tried correctly? Here's my session: ... (I'll edit it in the post)

Comment: I'm not sure you even need the `decode` call (based only on it working when I try without).

Comment: Make sure you put the decode('utf8') at the very end. I can only reproduce what you get if I do the decoding in the wrong place.

Comment: Trengot: technically it is not necessary. However, in python is is generally recommended to convert all your text in unicode as soon as possible, so you don't need to worry about encodings when you pass this to other functions.

Comment: @yak, you mut use a display method that's compatible with utf-8 if your python is expecting an ascii display it will not attempt to display non-ascii symbols.

Answer (score 30):

For Python 3, using [`urllib.parse.unquote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote):

```
from urllib.parse import unquote

print(unquote("Lech_Kaczy%C5%84ski"))
```

Output:

```
Lech_Kaczyński
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
import urllib

print urllib.unquote('Lech_Kaczy%C5%84ski')
```

Prints out

```
Lech_Kaczyński
```