# Text conversion issue in python

Tags: python, text

I have some texts like bellow:

```
%d8%b3%d9%88%d8%a6%ab%8c%da%86
```

I have tried to change it Arabic as bellow:

```
import binascii    
print(binascii.unhexlify(''.join('%d8%b3%d9%88%d8%a6%ab%8c%da%86'.split('%'))).decode('ISO-8859-1').encode('utf8').decode('mac-arabic'))
```

But I was not successful and the result is :

```
أ»آ٣أôآàأ»آ&آ+آ«أöآÜ
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I encode and decode percent-encoded (URL encoded) strings in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33143504/how-can-i-encode-and-decode-percent-encoded-url-encoded-strings-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct code is:

```
import binascii    
print(binascii.unhexlify(''.join('%d8%b3%d9%88%d8%a6%db%8c%da%86'.split('%'))).decode('utf-8'))
```