# Python requests: how to convert Percent-encoding to lower cases?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am using `requests` for the website `jp.123rf.com`. However, I noticed that when URL contains Percent-encodings that are upper cases, e.g., `%E9%A3%9B%E8%BA%8D`, it will return 302 and ask you to use the lower cases. Then `requests` will converts the lower cases to upper cases before accessing the new url, resulting in an infinite loop.

I tried to explicitly convert the Percent-encodings by `requests.get('https://jp.123rf.com/stock-photo/{}.html'.format(quote(query).lower())` but `requests` still automatically converts them to upper cases.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I encode/decode percent-encoded (URL) strings in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33143504/how-do-i-encode-decode-percent-encoded-url-strings-in-python)